# Firestore: how do I add a document and a subcollection document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, crud

In Flutter Firestore I do this to add a document:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('groups').add({'name': 'Group Name 1'});
```

But how do I add a document AND add a document in a subcollection as well, I need something like this:

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('groups').add({'name': 'Group Name 1'})
    .collection('members').add({'name': 'newMemberName', 'isAdmin': true});
```

(in this case, I want the user who created the group to be the first member, and an admin as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That first `add` returns a "future" that resolves to the doc reference of the new doc.  You can use that value by "await"-ing for it...

```
var docRef = await Firestore.instance.collection('groups').add({'name': 'Group Name 1'});
docRef.collection('members').add({'name': 'newMemberName', 'isAdmin': true});
```

Edit

To handle in a single http request, you might try a write batch.

Paul Edit:

```
      // Add new group to database
      var batch = Firestore.instance.batch();

      // Create the group
      var newGroup = Firestore.instance.collection('groups').document();
      batch.setData(newGroup, {'name': value});

      // Create the new members subcollection
      var newMember = newGroup.collection('members').document();
      batch.setData(newMember, {
        'users_documentId': currentUser.documentId,
        'users_displayName': currentUser.displayName,
        'isAdmin': true
      });

      // Commit the batch edits
      batch.commit().catchError((err) {
        print(err);
      });
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. But is there no way to do this with a single "http call"

Comment: @PaulKruger, I've never done it in dart, but (maybe??) an alternative is a write batch.  Here's a JS reference...https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch

Comment: Thanks man! This should put me on the right direction at least :)

Comment: glad to help. edited to suggest -- not with high confidence -- a write batch approach

Comment: DUDE THANK YOU! My next stack question would've been "how to batch edit", but thanks to your code I figured it out! I added the correct code to your answer. Just delete your stuff and use mine instead...thank you very very much!!!